# manipulate unknown database file

Tags: database

I have a database file ending in .dat, which says nothing to me. Given that it uses a file per database, I assumed that it had to be some sort of sqlite, so tried to open with sqlite3 and has not been recognized as a database. Due to licensing issues, I'm unsure of how much information I can share about this, so I won't be able to upload the file. I know that it's not an encrypted file, and if I cat the file it looks like this:

```
<FE>^_(^@SR<89>^@^@^F^@^@^@Z^@^@^@XXX.Bin 6^RXXX.BankName s80^RXXX.CardType1 7^RXXX.CardType2 F^RXXX.Country Q^RXXX.BankPhone Q^R^T^F^D^C^C^X^@400094^R^@^@^@STAR_NETWORKS,_INCN/AN/AUNITED_STATES_OF_AMERICA^F^D^C^C^X^@400109^R^@^@^@EFUNDS_CORPORATIONN/AN/AUNITED_STATES_OF_AMERICA^F^D^C^C^X^@400110^P^@^@^@FIFTH_THIRD_BANKN/AN/AUNITED_STATES_OF_AMERICA^F^D^C^C^X^@
```

Any help on how I could export this to a sqlite database? If I only knew what type of database this is! I know that it's read by a program for windows and I'm trying to avoid making a script to read it character by character (there are no return lines) so any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know which programs use it?  Can you include a "hex dump" of the first 15-20 characters?

Comment: the program that uses it is a standalone exe and I have no access to the source code

Comment: Do you know which language the program was written in?  In many cases this can help to narrow down which database technology is _probably_ being used.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't, and the gui looks quite strange to me. Running strings on the binary doesn't return anything helpful and I can't post the hexdump of the binary because of the limit on the number of characters. I can tell, though, that it begins with a MZP

Comment: Just the first 15-20 characters is all that's needed -- that will easily fit into a comment (up to 60 characters if you include spaces between the pairs of hexadecimal nybbles).

Comment: 0000000 5a4d 0050 0002 0000 0004 000f ffff 0000

0000010 00b8 0000 0000 0000 0040 001a 0000 0000

0000020 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

0000030 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000

0000040 10ba 0e00 b41f cd09 b821 4c01 21cd 9090

0000050 6854 7369 7020 6f72 7267 6d61 6d20 7375

0000060 2074 6562 7220 6e75 7520 646e 7265 5720

0000070 6e69 3233 0a0d 3724 0000 0000 0000 0000

0000080 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Comment: @omtinez: could you post the name of the file and program and the language (e.g. English) of it? I used `xxd -r file > testfile` to reconstruct the file from the hexdump (and verified the dump with `xxd testfile`), but unfortunately `file testfile` still says "data". Not really useful.

Comment: When "5A 4D" is swapped around, it comes out as "MZ" which is typical of DLL and other executable files in Windows.  This really is starting to look more like a program file, and I wonder if it might be a self-modifying DLL.  It could also be a "**Mountable Zip File**."

Comment: oh wait were you requesting the hezdump of the file, or the executable program that reads it? I gave you the hexdump of the executable, I will post the file in a second

Comment: 0000000 1ffe 0028 5253 0089 0600 0000 5a00 0000
0000010 5800 5858 422e 6e69 3620 5812 5858 422e
0000020 6e61 4e6b 6d61 2065 3873 1230 5858 2e58
0000030 6143 6472 7954 6570 2031 1237 5858 2e58
0000040 6143 6472 7954 6570 2032 1246 5858 2e58
0000050 6f43 6e75 7274 2079 1251 5858 2e58 6142
0000060 6b6e 6850 6e6f 2065 1251 0614 0304 1803
0000070 3400 3030 3930 1234 0000 5300 4154 5f52
0000080 454e 5754 524f 534b 5f2c 4e49 4e43 412f

Comment: Still data: `printf '\xfe\x1f\x28\x00\x53\x52\x89\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x5a\x00\x00\x00\x58\x58\x58\x2e\x42\x69\x6e\x20\x36\x12\x58\x58\x58\x2e\x42\x61\x6e\x6b\x4e\x61\x6d\x65\x20\x73\x38\x30\x12\x58\x58\x58\x2e\x43\x61\x72\x64\x54\x79\x70\x65\x31\x20\x37\x12\x58\x58\x58\x2e\x43\x61\x72\x64\x54\x79\x70\x65\x32\x20\x46\x12\x58\x58\x58\x2e\x43\x6f\x75\x6e\x74\x72\x79\x20\x51\x12\x58\x58\x58\x2e\x42\x61\x6e\x6b\x50\x68\x6f\x6e\x65\x20\x51\x12\x14\x06\x04\x03\x03\x18\x00\x34\x30\x30\x30\x39\x34\x12\x00\x00\x00\x53\x54\x41\x52\x5f\x4e\x45\x54\x57\x4f\x52\x4b\x53\x2c\x5f\x49\x4e\x43\x4e\x2f\x41'`

Comment: @omtinez:  I thought you were asking about the database file that you were trying to alter -- I was definitely interested in the data file.  Thanks for clarifying.  I'm not seeing any indication of what type of file this is either.  It could be a proprietary data file format for all we know.

Comment: Presumably what you are really after is the data itself, the database being but a stepping stone to get there. If so, a last resort might be to reverse engineer the data format itself and write a program to extract the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

`file` can identify many file types by examining the file contents. Usage:

```
file filename
```

I tried to reconstruct a part of your file from the data you provided, by using:

```
printf '\xfe\x1F(\0SR\x89\0\0\6\0\0\0Z\0\0\0XXX.Bin 6\x12XXX.BankName s80\x12XXX.CardType1' > testfile
```

Unfortunately, `file testfile` does not give any (useful) results:

```
testfile: data
```

You might have more luck by using `file` on the whole file.

Programs have often an own format for storing data which is optimized for its tasks. If you cannot find the files format, try Google. Another useful tool for extracting information is the `strings` program, which can be run with `strings filename`.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion (+1).

Comment: I don't know how I didn't think of this before! Unfortunately, it also returns data on the entire file

Comment: I did think of running strings, but it didn't return anything that could make sense